# IOS Bluetooth(BLE) CBPeripheralManager service broadcasting

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheralmanager

How to embed two services in CBPeripheralManager and broadcast.

service1 - Info(Read characteristic), Key (Write Characteristic)
service2 - Data(modified based on Key received in service1)

My app design is like first service will have basic info with a write characteristic of key, If didReceiveWriteRequests receives key, Based on that I have to do some changes in characteristic data in second service and broadcast.

I tried like adding two service like below but it is not working. How to broadcast service2? after service1. Any Suggestion would be helpful.

```
    [self.peripheralManager addService:self.service1];
    [self.peripheralManager addService:self.service2];
```

Comment: It isn't clear why you have added a second service. It seems that one service could provide all of the characteristics, but regardless what is the specific problem you are having? Are you advertising both services or only the first.  Aphis are you discovering the services on the central side.